# How to migrate table in october cms?

Tags: php, laravel, content-management-system, octobercms

When I migrate the table, the `php artisan migrate` does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use composer.
Navigate to the root directory of the project. Run,

```
php artisan october:up
```

if you want to roalback you can run

```
php artisan october:down
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use composer in the project directory

`php artisan migrate:refresh` `php artisan migrate:rollback` `php artisan migrate --force` are some cmd's you could try. I don't know if this helps you otherwise please explain your question a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the root directory of your project in command prompt and run these commands

- To reset the current migrations if there are some `php artisan migrate:reset`
- then run `php artisan migrate`